# AutoIt send command in IE in Kiosk mode

Tags: autoit

I'm really new to coding (like very new) but I managed to do what I wanted with AutoIt. That means: Launch IE automatically on a certain web page in Kiosk mode. So far so good.

But before I was not in kiosk mode the input sent worked but now I can't find the problem why it does not work any more.

```
ShellExecuteWait("c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "-k http://website.com", "")

WinWaitActive("website.com  Login - Internet Explorer","")

Send("login{TAB}password{ENTER}")
```

The website is launched, I'm directly in the login box, but nothing is typed in it. Any ideas?

Comment: because focus might not be on the login box?

Comment: That was indeed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Steve said in the comments, you can try to use [ControlFocus](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlFocus.htm) when the window is shown, then send the credentials.

```
ShellExecuteWait("c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "-k http://website.com", "")

; store the returned window handle to use it in the ControlFocus call
Local $hWnd = WinWaitActive("website.com  Login - Internet Explorer","")

ControlFocus($hWnd, "", "Edit1")

Send("login{TAB}password{ENTER}")
```

Comment: That was indeed the ControlFocus. I missed it. Because before I set up IE in kiosk mode it was not needed. Thanks for your time. I'm still learning.